# How to login to APEX190200 application using R web-scraping (e.g. POST request)

Tags: authentication, oracle-apex, rvest, httr, oracle-apex-5

I'm not an expert in authentication stuff.

I have been tasked with fixing an R shiny app (not mine) that performs some web-scraping on an Oracle APEX application. The login procedure worked in the past when APEX050000 was in use, but started failing with APEX was updated to version 190200.

The [Oracle APEX change log](https://apex.oracle.com/en/learn/documentation/release-notes/) shows a potentially interesting change in version 18.1:

> Social Authentication
>
> Developers can now easily create APEX applications which can use Oracle Identity Cloud Service, Google, Facebook, generic OpenID Connect and generic OAuth2 as the authentication method.

But I can't judge if that could have made the difference.

In the R shiny app, the form is submitted with a POST request (is it BASIC auth?). The code performs steps I cant explain, so I hope it speaks for itself. I simplified where I could:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

dv.login <- function(username, password){
  
  url = "http://ufo.some.url.nl/apex/f?p=200:LOGIN_DESKTOP::::::"
  dv_session <<- dv_session %>% rvest:::request_GET(url)
  
  form <- dv_session %>% html_nodes("form")
  action <- form %>% html_attr("action")  # wwv_flow.accept
  inputs <- form %>% html_nodes("input")
  
  for (inp in inputs) { 
    name <- inp %>% html_attr("name", default = "-")
    if (name == "-") {next}
    value <- input %>% html_nodes("option[selected=selected]") %>% html_attr("value")
    
    keys <- c(keys, name)
    values <- c(values, value)
  }
  post_params <- as.list(values)
  names(post_params) <- keys
  
  post_params["p_md5_checksum"]  <- dv_session %>% html_nodes("input[name=p_md5_checksum]") %>% html_attr("value")
  post_params["p_page_checksum"] <- dv_session %>% html_nodes("input[name=p_page_checksum]") %>% html_attr("value")
  post_params["p_request"] <- "LOGIN"
  post_params["p_t01"] <- username
  post_params["p_t02"] <- password
  
  url_post = "http://ufo.some.url.nl/apex/wwv_flow.accept"
  dv.POST_request(url_post, post_params)
  dv_session <<- dv_session %>%
    rvest:::request_POST(url_post,
                         body = post_params,
                         encode = "form")
  
  if (username %in% dv_session$response$cookies$value) {
    instance <<- post_params$p_instance
    
    username <<- username
    password <<- password
    login_correct <<- TRUE
    return('succes')
  }
  login_error <<- "Wrong username or password"
  return('fail')
}
```

### Issue

The "**p_md5_checksum**" and "**p_page_checksum**" values cannot be found anymore!
I tried to find alternative html nodes that contain these checksums, but it seems it is not there...
In other words, the node matching the xpath `input[name=p_md5_checksum]` does not exist anymore.

I tried it with the `pPageItemsProtected` and `pPageFormRegionChecksums` values of respectively `[]` and `Gnxyk3e2EUyHfpQDZWCMtQ`, but received a `404 - page not found` (If I remember correctly).

Beside this primary issue, I doubt if the password and username `post_param` fields are correct, they were `p_t01` and `p_t02`, but that's not something I can find in the HTML... should it be there?

### HTML

I could obtain the HTML by running:

```
httr::content(dv.session$response, as="text")
```

(I don't have a browser's "webdeveloper tools" because I can only access it from a restricted Citrix environment where that's disabled)

Result:

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:htmldb="http://htmldb.oracle.com">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/themes/theme_20/theme_4_0.css" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/themes/theme_20/ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/app_ui/css/Core.min.css?v=19.2.0.00.18" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/app_ui/css/Theme-Standard.min.css?v=19.2.0.00.18" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/libraries/jquery-ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui-apex.min.css?v=19.2.0.00.18" type="text/css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/legacy_ui/css/5.0.min.css?v=19.2.0.00.18" type="text/css" />



  <script>
    var apex_img_dir = "/i/",
      htmldb_Img_Dir = apex_img_dir;
  </script>
  <script src="/i/libraries/apex/minified/desktop_all.min.js?v=19.2.0.00.18"></script>
  <script src="wwv_flow.js_messages?p_app_id=200&p_lang=en&p_version=19.2.0.00.18-10662680120535"></script>
  <script src="/i/libraries/apex/minified/legacy_pre18.min.js?v=19.2.0.00.18"></script>
  <script src="/i/libraries/apex/minified/legacy_18.min.js?v=19.2.0.00.18"></script>
  <script src="/i/libraries/jquery-migrate/3.0.1/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js?v=19.2.0.00.18"></script>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
</head>

<body>
  <form action="wwv_flow.accept" method="post" name="wwv_flow" id="wwvFlowForm" data-oj-binding-provider="none" novalidate autocomplete="off">

    <input type="hidden" name="p_flow_id" value="200" id="pFlowId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p_flow_step_id" value="101" id="pFlowStepId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p_instance" value="10532003874288" id="pInstance" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p_page_submission_id" value="321620263451736796746631187861272947304" id="pPageSubmissionId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p_request" value="" id="pRequest" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p_reload_on_submit" value="A" id="pReloadOnSubmit" />
    <input type="hidden" value="321620263451736796746631187861272947304" id="pSalt" />
    <div id="t20PageHeader">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="">
        <tr>
          <td id="t20Logo" valign="top"><span class="apex-logo-text">some_tool</span><br /></td>
          <td id="t20HeaderMiddle" valign="top" width="100%"><br /></td>
          <td id="t20NavBar" valign="top"><a href="apex_authentication.logout&#x3F;p_app_id&#x3D;200&#x26;p_session_id&#x3D;10532003874288" class="t20NavBar">Logout</a> |<br /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="t20BreadCrumbsLeft"></div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="" id="t20PageBody" height="70%" align="center" width="400">
      <td width="100%" valign="top" height="100%" id="t20ContentBody" align="center">
        <div id="t20Messages"><span id="APEX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE" data-template-id="59041209344594598_S" class="apex-page-success u-hidden"></span><span id="APEX_ERROR_MESSAGE" data-template-id="59041209344594598_E" class="apex-page-error u-hidden"></span></div>
        <div id="t20ContentMiddle">
          <table class="t20Region t20FormRegion" id="R59048808018594617" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="t20RegionHeader" id="R59048808018594617_header">Login</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="R59048808018594617_body">
              <tr>
                <td class="t20ButtonHolder"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="t20RegionBody">
                  <table id="apex_layout_59048808018594617" border="0" class="formlayout" role="presentation">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right"><label for="P101_USERNAME" id="P101_USERNAME_LABEL" tabindex="999"><a class="t20OptionalLabelwithHelp" href="javascript:popupFieldHelp('59048902184594617','10532003874288')" tabindex="999">Username</a></label></td>
                      <td align="left"><input type="text" id="P101_USERNAME" name="P101_USERNAME" class="text_field&#x20;apex-item-text" value="" size="40" maxlength="100" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="right"><label for="P101_PASSWORD" id="P101_PASSWORD_LABEL" tabindex="999"><a class="t20OptionalLabelwithHelp" href="javascript:popupFieldHelp('59049017764594617','10532003874288')" tabindex="999">Password</a></label></td>
                      <td align="left"><input type="password" name="P101_PASSWORD" size="40" maxlength="100" value="" id="P101_PASSWORD" class="password&#x20;apex-item-text" onkeypress="return apex.submit({request:'P101_PASSWORD',submitIfEnter:event})" /></td>
                      <td align="left"><a href="javascript:apex.submit(%7Brequest:&#x27;LOGIN&#x27;%7D);" class="t20Button" id="P101_LOGIN">Login</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" width="200" id="t20ContentRight"><br /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="" id="t20PageFooter" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td id="t20Left" valign="top"><span id="t20UserPrompt">nobody</span><br /></td>
        <td id="t20Center" valign="top"></td>
        <td id="t20Right" valign="top"><span id="t20Customize"></span><br /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br class="t20Break" />
    <input type="hidden" id="pPageFormRegionChecksums" value="&#x5B;&#x5D;">
    <input type="hidden" id="pPageItemsRowVersion" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="pPageItemsProtected" value="Gnxyk3e2EUyHfpQDZWCMtQ" /></form>







  <script type="text/javascript">
    apex.jQuery(function() {
      apex.page.init(this, function() {
        apex.jQuery.when.apply(apex.jQuery, apex.page.loadingDeferreds).done(function() {
          try {
            (function() {
              var lTimeoutField = document.getElementById("apex_login_throttle_sec"),
                lTimeout = lTimeoutField ? +lTimeoutField.innerHTML : 0;
              if (lTimeout) {
                var lTimer = window.setInterval(
                  function() {
                    if (lTimeout > 0) {
                      lTimeoutField.innerHTML = lTimeout;
                      lTimeout--;
                    } else {
                      window.clearInterval(lTimer);
                      var lDiv = document.getElementById("apex_login_throttle_div");
                      if (lDiv) {
                        lDiv.parentNode.removeChild(lDiv);
                        return true;
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  1000);
              }
            })();


            apex.item('P101_USERNAME').setFocus();
          } finally {
            apex.event.trigger(apex.gPageContext$, 'apexreadyend');
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```